# passing json data from controller to directive & displaying in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm having issue passing JSON data from controller to directive in Angular js. Below is the code which contains the controller & directive elements:

```
  var app = angular.module('chartApp',[]) ;   
  app.controller('DataController', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.lineData = { 
              "x": 1,
              "y": 5
            }, {
              "x": 20,
              "y": 20
            }, {
              "x": 40,
              "y": 10
            }, {
              "x": 60,
              "y": 40
            }, {
              "x": 80,
              "y": 5
            }, {
              "x": 100,
              "y": 60
        }



  }]);      

 app.directive('lineChart',function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope:{
                chartData: '='
            },

        template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="prop in customer">{{chartData.x}}</li></ul>'

        //template:'xValue: {{lineData.x}} yValue: {{lineData.y}}'

    } ;

    });
```

Below is the html view part of the code:

```
<body>
<div ng-app="chartApp" ng-controller="DataController">
      <h1>Pareto Chart</h1>
  <div Line-Chart chart-data='lineData' ></div>

</div>
</body>
```

When I try to run the above code, the JSON data is not getting displayed in the template. Its neither throwing any error. Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: you use isolated scope, that not contains `customer` so ng-repeat alwasy do nothing

Comment: What is `ng-repeat="prop in customer"` referring to? It is possible the `ng-repeat` never runs.

Answer (score 4):

you use isolated scope, that not contains customer so ng-repeat alwasy do nothing.

Just change it to `chartData` and inside use `prop.x`

```js
var app = angular.module('chartApp', []);
app.controller('DataController', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.lineData = [{
      "x": 1,
      "y": 5
    }, {
      "x": 20,
      "y": 20
    }, {
      "x": 40,
      "y": 10
    }, {
      "x": 60,
      "y": 40
    }, {
      "x": 80,
      "y": 5
    }, {
      "x": 100,
      "y": 60
    }];
  }
]);

app.directive('lineChart', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      chartData: '='
    },

    template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="prop in chartData">{{prop.x}}</li></ul>'

    //template:'xValue: {{lineData.x}} yValue: {{lineData.y}}'

  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="chartApp" ng-controller="DataController">
  <h1>Pareto Chart</h1>
  <div Line-Chart chart-data='lineData'></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi Grundy, thanks for the reply. But in the above code, you have included an array. But I wanted to pass json object and not array.

Comment: @vr3w3c9, so, can you provide sample for object? in your sample rather typo because you get syntax error for this

Comment: Im able to populate the data by creating an array. But all I wanted is creating an isolated scope and pass the json from Controller to directive. With the above sample object when I use via inherited scope, the data gets displayed fine.

Comment: @vr3w3c9, i'm a bit confused, so your problem solved? :-)